# please add a full log with log_level = 2 any one answer lease?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, linux, kivy

I want to build an app with bulldozer.

I get the following error message:

> code for the program

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
class MainApp(MDApp):// python programming for UI attached in class
def build(self):
    self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"  # "Purple", "Red"

    screen = Screen()
    screen.add_widget(
        MDRectangleFlatButton(
            text="Hello, World",
            pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5},
        )
    )
    return screen
```

*Main class run*

Buildozer failed to execute the last command. The error might be hidden in the log above this error. Please read the full log, and search for it before. raising an issue with buildozer itself. In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2.

Can anyone help me?

```
 MainApp().run()
```

> android debug from program

```
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp -- 
bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,kivymd --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always -- 
storage-dir="/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CUDNN_VERSION = '7.6.5.32'
#     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
#     CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     HOSTNAME = '7cfc4b566476'
#     OLDPWD = '/'
#     CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config'
#     NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all'
#     DATALAB_SETTINGS_OVERRIDES = 
    '{"kernelManagerProxyPort":6000,"kernelManagerProxyHost":"172.28.0.3","jupyterArgs":["-- 
ip=\\"172.28.0.2\\""],"debugAdapterMultiplexerPath":"/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer"}'
#     ENV = '/root/.bashrc'
#     PAGER = 'cat'
#     NCCL_VERSION = '2.8.3'
#     TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true'
#     JPY_PARENT_PID = '50'
#     NO_GCE_CHECK = 'True'
#     PWD = '/content'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20210119'
#     CLICOLOR = '1'
#     DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive'
#     LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
#     GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '0'
#     GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008'
#     TERM = 'xterm-color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16'
#     PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
#     MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
#     CUDA_PKG_VERSION = '10-1=10.1.243-1'
#     CUDA_VERSION = '10.1.243'
#     NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     PYTHONPATH = '/env/python'
#     NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA = ('cuda>=10.1 brand=tesla,driver>=396,driver<397 '
'brand=tesla,driver>=410,driver<411 brand=tesla,driver>=418,driver<419')
#     COLAB_GPU = '0'
#     GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#PATH= '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apacheant-
.9.4/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr
/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/opt/bin'
#     LD_PRELOAD = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4'
#     GIT_PAGER = 'cat'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: When it says "please add a full log", it means the whole thing, not just the few lines at the end that you've pasted.

Answer (score 0):

**The Google Colab Way!**
The conversion requires a Linux environment and Google provides it for free! If you belong to Data Science or Deep learning background then you must be aware of this platform. It provides you a virtual machine with 75GB space, 12GB RAM, and around 12GB GPU power! You can use this platform to perform model training, checking logs, or running Python codes.
As this is a Linux based system, now the only thing required is to install the dependencies and initiate the process. You can directly use my colab notebook where you just need to run all the cells, that’s it!

```
Open In Colab
In [ ]: !pip install buildozer
In [ ]: !pip install cython==0.29.19
In [ ]: !sudo apt-get install -y \
            python3-pip \
            build-essential \
            git \
            python3 \
            python3-dev \
            ffmpeg \
            libsdl2-dev \
            libsdl2-image-dev \
            libsdl2-mixer-dev \
            libsdl2-ttf-dev \
            libportmidi-dev \
            libswscale-dev \
            libavformat-dev \
            libavcodec-dev \
            zlib1g-dev
In [ ]: !sudo apt-get install -y \
           libgstreamer1.0 \
           gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
           gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
In [ ]: !sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi6
In [ ]: !sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
In [ ]: !buildozer init
In [ ]: !buildozer -v android debug
In [ ]: !buildozer android clean
In [ ]:
```

**Before running the cells, make sure to upload your app code to the colab notebook and after running the bulldozer init command, make sure to edit the specs file generated and nothing else!
This is the easiest and most convenient way to build apps without the need for an actual system! But can we go even more simple? Let’s see**